Exception "ValueError" with Keras Lambda layer in TensorFlow 2.16
I'm new to Tensorflow and I followed a couple of tutorials to learn more about it.
My last tutorial was about transformer models and how to use them for chat.
The model compiled fine with TensorFlow 2.15 but the exception is showing up with TensorFlow 2.16. I have no clue how to solve it:
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: 256 (of type <class 'int'>)

The exception happens in the lambda layer:
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = (None,), name = "inputs")
  padding_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 1, None), name = "padding_mask")

  embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocabulary_size, model)(inputs)
  embeddings *= tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
      lambda model: tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(model, tf.float32))
  )(model)


You are not defining model anywhere in the code you posted, so it's really not possible to say anything here.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding
Describes tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, ...)
You have "model" as output_dim which is likely a mistake.

Not sure about that. I've double checked with the code exsamples and it's the same code.
But I've now downgraded from TF 2.16 to 2.15 and that is getting rid of the exception.

Look at the documentation /shrug. The 2nd argument is definitely output_dim.

yeah that's clear in the docs but there is no change from TF 2.15 to 2.16
What I meant is that I'm not sure about the intention of it in the example code. Model is an integer and the value of it makes sense to be used as a dimension. The naming of the variable in the example is not the best.
